# Score function for GridSearchCV with GaussianMixture

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to train a `GaussianMixture` model. I want to select the number of components based on a cross-validation score. I want the score function to be the log likelihood of my dataset. Such method is defined inside the `GaussianMixture` class and it is called `score`.

I am trying to pass this function as an argument of `GridSearchCV`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Data generation
mean = (1, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
n_samples = 1000
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, n_samples)

# Model definition
model = GaussianMixture(covariance_type='full')

# Grid search
param_grid = [{'n_components': [1, 2]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, cv=3, scoring=model.score, return_train_score=True) 
grid_search.fit(X)
```

But this raises the error:

```
NotFittedError: This GaussianMixture instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

How can I use the `score` method defined in `GaussianMixture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `score` method to assess perfomance of a *fitted* model on new data, using predefined metric (e.g. log-likelihood in this case). So you can't pass it to `GridSearch` since it refits a model for each split and also since this method is not a valid [scoring function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter): scoring function should take `(y_true, y_predicted)` values and return a number.

But if scoring function is not specified the `GridSearchCV` [uses](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) estimator's `score` method anyway, so you don't need to specify it.